# What is the disassembler telling me?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, debugging, qt-creator

Application is crashing, so I started it on debug mode and there I got the message that a write access violation is happening.
Additionnally Qt Creator pointed me to the disassembler showing the following:

[image]

```
        ntdll!RtlWaitOnAddress:
0x7fff9dfd3350                   sub     rsp,38h
0x7fff9dfd3354  <+    4>         mov     eax,dword ptr [ntdll!NlsAnsiCodePage+0x1360 (00007fff`9e0d8b2c)]
0x7fff9dfd335a  <+   10>         mov     dword ptr [rsp+20h],eax
0x7fff9dfd335e  <+   14>         call    ntdll!RtlWaitOnAddress+0x254 (00007fff`9dfd35a4)
0x7fff9dfd3363  <+   19>         add     rsp,38h
0x7fff9dfd3367  <+   23>         ret
0x7fff9dfd3368  <+   24>         int     3
0x7fff9dfd3369  <+   25>         int     3
0x7fff9dfd336a  <+   26>         int     3
0x7fff9dfd336b  <+   27>         int     3
0x7fff9dfd336c  <+   28>         int     3
0x7fff9dfd336d  <+   29>         int     3
0x7fff9dfd336e  <+   30>         int     3
0x7fff9dfd336f  <+   31>         int     3
0x7fff9dfd3370  <+   32>         mov     qword ptr [rsp+18h],rbx
0x7fff9dfd3375  <+   37>         push    rbp
0x7fff9dfd3376  <+   38>         push    rsi
0x7fff9dfd3377  <+   39>         push    rdi
0x7fff9dfd3378  <+   40>         push    r12
0x7fff9dfd337a  <+   42>         push    r13
0x7fff9dfd337c  <+   44>         push    r14
0x7fff9dfd337e  <+   46>         push    r15
0x7fff9dfd3380  <+   48>         sub     rsp,0A0h
0x7fff9dfd3387  <+   55>         mov     rax,qword ptr [ntdll!KiUserInvertedFunctionTable+0x3010 (00007fff`9e0f2510)]
0x7fff9dfd338e  <+   62>         xor     rax,rsp
0x7fff9dfd3391  <+   65>         mov     qword ptr [rsp+90h],rax
0x7fff9dfd3399  <+   73>         mov   r13,qword ptr gs:[30h]
0x7fff9dfd33a2  <+   82>         lea     rax,[ntdll!RtlNtdllName+0x470c8 (00007fff`9e0d44f8)]
0x7fff9dfd33a9  <+   89>         xor     bpl,bpl
0x7fff9dfd33ac  <+   92>         mov     dword ptr [rsp+48h],edx
0x7fff9dfd33b0  <+   96>         xor     esi,esi
0x7fff9dfd33b2  <+   98>         mov     byte ptr [rsp+40h],bpl
0x7fff9dfd33b7  <+  103>         mov     qword ptr [rsp+50h],r13
0x7fff9dfd33bc  <+  108>         mov     rbx,rcx
0x7fff9dfd33bf  <+  111>         mov     r12d,esi
0x7fff9dfd33c2  <+  114>         cmp     rcx,rax
0x7fff9dfd33c5  <+  117>         je      ntdll!RtlWaitOnAddress+0x1b4 (00007fff`9dfd3504)
0x7fff9dfd33cb  <+  123>         cmp     byte ptr [ntdll!NlsAnsiCodePage+0x2d3c (00007fff`9e0da508)],sil
0x7fff9dfd33d2  <+  130>         jne     ntdll!RtlWaitOnAddress+0x230 (00007fff`9dfd3580)
0x7fff9dfd33d8  <+  136>         cmp     dword ptr [ntdll!NlsAnsiCodePage+0x2d5c (00007fff`9e0da528)],esi
0x7fff9dfd33de  <+  142>         jne     ntdll!RtlWaitOnAddress+0x1fe (00007fff`9dfd354e)
0x7fff9dfd33e4  <+  148>         cmp     byte ptr [ntdll!NlsAnsiCodePage+0x282c (00007fff`9e0d9ff8)],sil
0x7fff9dfd33eb  <+  155>         lea     rdi,[ntdll!NlsAnsiCodePage+0x2834 (00007fff`9e0da000)]
0x7fff9dfd33f2  <+  162>         cmovne  rdi,rsi
0x7fff9dfd33f6  <+  166>         cmp     qword ptr [rbx+18h],rsi
0x7fff9dfd33fa  <+  170>         je      ntdll!RtlWaitOnAddress+0x182 (00007fff`9dfd34d2)
0x7fff9dfd3400  <+  176>         mov     rax,qword ptr [rbx]
0x7fff9dfd3403  <+  179>         cmp     rax,0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFh
0x7fff9dfd3407  <+  183>         je      ntdll!RtlWaitOnAddress+0x18f (00007fff`9dfd34df)
0x7fff9dfd340d  <+  189>         mov     r15d,esi
0x7fff9dfd3410  <+  192>         cmp     rax,0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFh
0x7fff9dfd3414  <+  196>         je      ntdll!RtlWaitOnAddress+0xc9 (00007fff`9dfd3419)
0x7fff9dfd3416  <+  198>         inc     dword ptr [rax+24h]
0x7fff9dfd3419  <+  201>         mov     r14,qword ptr [rbx+18h]
0x7fff9dfd341d  <+  205>         lea     r13,[ntdll!RtlNtdllName+0x470c8 (00007fff`9e0d44f8)]
0x7fff9dfd3424  <+  212>         mov     ebp,1722h
0x7fff9dfd3429  <+  217>         call    ntdll!RtlGetCurrentServiceSessionId (00007fff`9df94850)
0x7fff9dfd342e  <+  222>         test    eax,eax
0x7fff9dfd3430  <+  224>         jne     ntdll!memset+0x1a8f4 (00007fff`9e02e6f4)
0x7fff9dfd3436  <+  230>         mov     ecx,offset SharedUserData+0x382 (00000000`7ffe0382)
0x7fff9dfd343b  <+  235>         cmp     byte ptr [rcx],0
0x7fff9dfd343e  <+  238>         jne     ntdll!memset+0x1a910 (00007fff`9e02e710)
0x7fff9dfd3444  <+  244>         cmp     r14,0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFh
0x7fff9dfd3448  <+  248>         jne     ntdll!memset+0x1a9a8 (00007fff`9e02e7a8)
0x7fff9dfd344e  <+  254>         mov     r9,rdi
0x7fff9dfd3451  <+  257>         mov     dword ptr [rsp+20h],0
0x7fff9dfd3459  <+  265>         mov     r8d,4
0x7fff9dfd345f  <+  271>         lea     rdx,[rsp+48h]
0x7fff9dfd3464  <+  276>         lea     rcx,[rbx+8]
0x7fff9dfd3468  <+  280>         call    ntdll!RtlWaitOnAddress+0x254 (00007fff`9dfd35a4)
0x7fff9dfd346d  <+  285>         cmp     eax,102h
0x7fff9dfd3472  <+  290>         je      ntdll!memset+0x1a9bb (00007fff`9e02e7bb)
0x7fff9dfd3478  <+  296>         mov     ecx,dword ptr [rbx+8]
0x7fff9dfd347b  <+  299>         mov     dword ptr [rsp+48h],ecx
0x7fff9dfd347f  <+  303>         test    cl,2
0x7fff9dfd3482  <+  306>         jne     ntdll!RtlWaitOnAddress+0xfe (00007fff`9dfd344e)
0x7fff9dfd3484  <+  308>         cmp     eax,102h
0x7fff9dfd3489  <+  313>         je      ntdll!memset+0x1a9bb (00007fff`9e02e7bb)
0x7fff9dfd348f  <+  319>         movzx   ebp,byte ptr [rsp+40h]
0x7fff9dfd3494  <+  324>         mov     r13,qword ptr [rsp+50h]
0x7fff9dfd3499  <+  329>         test    eax,eax
0x7fff9dfd349b  <+  331>         js      ntdll!memset+0x1ab19 (00007fff`9e02e919)
0x7fff9dfd34a1  <+  337>         test    bpl,bpl
0x7fff9dfd34a4  <+  340>         jne     ntdll!RtlWaitOnAddress+0x1c9 (00007fff`9dfd3519)
0x7fff9dfd34a6  <+  342>         mov     rcx,qword ptr [rsp+90h]
0x7fff9dfd34ae  <+  350>         xor     rcx,rsp
0x7fff9dfd34b1  <+  353>         call    ntdll!RtlRetrieveNtUserPfn+0x110 (00007fff`9dffc230)
0x7fff9dfd34b6  <+  358>         mov     rbx,qword ptr [rsp+0F0h]
0x7fff9dfd34be  <+  366>         add     rsp,0A0h
0x7fff9dfd34c5  <+  373>         pop     r15
0x7fff9dfd34c7  <+  375>         pop     r14
0x7fff9dfd34c9  <+  377>         pop     r13
0x7fff9dfd34cb  <+  379>         pop     r12
0x7fff9dfd34cd  <+  381>         pop     rdi
0x7fff9dfd34ce  <+  382>         pop     rsi
0x7fff9dfd34cf  <+  383>         pop     rbp
0x7fff9dfd34d0  <+  384>         ret
0x7fff9dfd34d1  <+  385>         int     3
0x7fff9dfd34d2  <+  386>         mov     rcx,rbx
0x7fff9dfd34d5  <+  389>         call    ntdll!RtlWaitOnAddress+0x6e0 (00007fff`9dfd3a30)
0x7fff9dfd34da  <+  394>         jmp     ntdll!RtlWaitOnAddress+0xb0 (00007fff`9dfd3400)
0x7fff9dfd34df  <+  399>         mov     ecx,dword ptr [rbx+20h]
0x7fff9dfd34e2  <+  402>         mov     rax,0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFh
0x7fff9dfd34e9  <+  409>         bt      rcx,18h
0x7fff9dfd34ee  <+  414>         jb      ntdll!RtlWaitOnAddress+0xbd (00007fff`9dfd340d)
0x7fff9dfd34f4  <+  420>         mov     rcx,rbx
0x7fff9dfd34f7  <+  423>         call    ntdll!LdrGetDllPath+0x3f0 (00007fff`9df81840)
0x7fff9dfd34fc  <+  428>         mov     rax,qword ptr [rbx]
0x7fff9dfd34ff  <+  431>         jmp     ntdll!RtlWaitOnAddress+0xbd (00007fff`9dfd340d)
0x7fff9dfd3504  <+  436>         mov     byte ptr [rsp+40h],1
0x7fff9dfd3509  <+  441>         mov dword ptr [r13+1760h],1
0x7fff9dfd3514  <+  452>         jmp     ntdll!RtlWaitOnAddress+0x7b (00007fff`9dfd33cb)
```

And pointed to line

```
(while pointing to `0x7fff9dfd3416  <+  198>         inc     dword ptr [rax+24h]` line):
```

How should I deal with this?

I'm in a Qt5 project using Microsoft compiler.

At application output terminal I see:

```
QCoreApplication::postEvent: Unexpected null receiver
```

Comment: This reads like you pass a null pointer somewhere. Could be an uninitialised object, a bad/missing copy constructor, ...

Comment: Take a look at the call stack and see if you can find your code in there. That could be where the problem started. `0x24 looks like a null pointer with a member variable offset.

Comment: In case if crash happens inside the `RtlWaitOnAddress`, then most probably the bug is somewhere below the stack.

Comment: What `below the stack` means? Does it mean the problem is on a library the application is calling?

Comment: @RetiredNinja from where do you get the inspiration to say `0x24` looks like a null pointer with a member variable offset?

Comment: @KcFnMi The address is not 0, so not a null pointer, but it seems pretty unlikely you'd end up with a pointer pointing to `0x24` naturally. One way that's really easy is `someStructOrClassNullPointer->someMember` where the member is at that offset.